# "Cannot GET /" error using Roots - CoffeeScript

Tags: node.js, get, coffeescript, connection, roots-toolkit

I am using [Roots](http://roots.cx) to develop an app, as I run `roots watch` command, then it compiles successfully and opens the `localhost:1111` page, but with the error below:

```
Cannot GET /
```

This is how my **app.coffee** file looks like, though I looked for a fix for this in SOF and none of them seemed to work for this case.

```
axis         = require 'axis'
rupture      = require 'rupture'
autoprefixer = require 'autoprefixer-stylus'
js_pipeline  = require 'js-pipeline'
css_pipeline = require 'css-pipeline'

module.exports =
  ignores: ['readme.md', '**/layout.*', '**/_*', '.gitignore', 'ship.*conf']

  extensions: [
    js_pipeline(files: 'assets/js/*.coffee'),
    css_pipeline(files: 'assets/css/*.styl')
  ]

  stylus:
    use: [axis(), rupture(), autoprefixer()]
    sourcemap: true

  'coffee-script':
    sourcemap: true

  jade:
    pretty: true
```

Is it a different solution since this is CoffeeScript instead of JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out to be the fact that I needed to `cd project-name` after I have done `roots new project-name`, and then only `roots watch` would work.

Such a rookie mistake, but a good lesson.